# iPhone 4 high res screen + high res Google maps custom icon?

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile, iphone-4

I'm using BG images twice the size of my element and using background-size attribute to take advantage of the high res iPhone 4 screen. I want to do this for the custom icon I am using in Google maps but as I can't use the background-size attribute on it, does anyone know of a way this might be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to [make sure your google maps icons are optimized for ios4 retina](http://samcroft.co.uk/2011/google-maps-marker-icons-for-iphone-retina-display/)

Hope this helps